# Summation Simplification involving binomial coefficient

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

May I know what is the approach of simplifying the summation:

[image]

Since the (-1)^m term alters between -1 and 1, is that possible that this summation eventually cancels to some concise expression involving powers?

Comment: It is $(1-3)^{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the binomial theorem: for any real numbers $x$ and $y$,
$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom{n}{m} x^m y^{n-m}.
$$

You can evaluate the original sum by realizing it as an instance of the binomial theorem.  First rewrite the original sum as
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom{n}{m} (-3)^m (1)^{n-m}
$$
(remember that $\binom{n}{m} = \binom{n}{n-m}$).  Then according to the binomial theorem, this sum is equal to
$$
(-3 + 1)^n = (-2)^n.
$$

Comment: Oops, sorry for this silly question since I failed to realize it is just straight up binomial theorem formula. Thank you for answering, greatly appreciated!